# java: setIconImages with an exe

Tags: java, icons, launcher, taskbar

I have a java project with Eclipse in Windows 7. Running my application from Eclipse, I have successfully changed the Taskbar icon using `setIconImages` (with a `List<Image>` from project resources, png files) on my main `JFrame`.

My target is to change **task bar icon** depending on an application state (from icon A to icon B, and back), and it works from eclipse.

Using an external tool (`install4j`), I have generated a Windows launcher (.exe) to execute my application, but using the launcher the taskbar icon does NOT change to icon B...

Images for icon B are in the same folder as other images used successfully in the application, is it different for taskbar icon? In fact, with launcher, after `setIconImages` icon B **is used** in other places of the application, like the icon displayed with the application using 'ALT-TAB'. But NOT the taskbar icon.

I have also tried to load an image at runtime from a local path and use it to set the application icon, but same result (it works but not in the taskbar icon)
Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,

Diego

Comment: Are those **ICONS** present in the directory from where you generated exe of your app !!

Comment: No code, no help. Not specifying the tool you used is not a good idea either.

Comment: Sorry if I did not explain properly my problem for the 1st time, I hope it is more clear now. Do you know what could be happening? Please tell me anything you consider. Thanks in advance